# Mongodb specifying type "string" returns "array" fields as well

Tags: mongodb

As you can test [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Sps4ps2JgtT), specifying `{"key": {$type: "string"}}` returns documents that have `key` field in type of array that contain strings in them.

In the example, I expected that the query should have returned only `{"key": "b"}`. How can get keys that only in type of `string`? I couldn't find in the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/).

Answer (score 9):

This is silly. When I change the query to:

```
  "key": {
    $type: "string",
    $not: {
      $type: "array"
    }
  }
```

it worked as expected...

Comment: It is a convenience function to allow an array and a single value to be used interchangeably in a document.

Answer (score 2):

[Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/#arrays) explains:

> For documents where field is an array, $type returns documents in which at least one array element matches a type passed to $type.

Comment: Yea I found it when I triple checked it :(